# WP AJAX is not working, always returns 0

Tags: plugin-development, ajax, wp-admin

I've checked any threads here regarding this and did a debug test which worked, I'd like to understand why my own code doesn't work as it presents the same functionality explained in every possible thread created about this issue.

I'm trying to send AJAX request when clicking on a checkbox and do some work with MySQL.

Here are some details to understand the scope and what was done:

```
var $ = jQuery;
$(function() {
    $('table.table').on('click', '[name="term-id"]', function() {
        var t = $(this),
            id = t.val(),
            checked = t.is(':checked');

        checkCategory(id, checked);
    });
});

function checkCategory(id, checked) {
    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {action: 'setAsyncCheckProduct', id: id, checked: checked},
        success: function(response) {
            alert(response);
        },
        error: function(errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    })
}
```

This script is included in my plugin via:

```
wp_enqueue_script('settings-manager', $this->pluginUrl . '/assets/js/SettingsManager.js');
```

In my main (abstract) plugin class (It is instantiated and is getting called, so I omit this code sample), but I add my async events assigned to admin_init:

```
add_action('admin_init', [$this, 'assignAsyncEvents']);
```

In my concrete classes, I implement this method like:

```
public function setAsyncCheckProduct()
{
    var_dump($_REQUEST);
    echo 123123123;
    wp_die();
}

public function assignAsyncEvents()
{
    add_action('wp_ajax_setAsyncCheckProduct', [$this, 'setAsyncCheckProduct']);
}
```

Which basically means:

> Send AJAX request to whatever is "ajaxurl" (which returns correct: /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php), action: setAsyncCheckProduct is sent along to the server, on the server, the assignAsyncEvents should be already done and a wp_ajax_MY_ACTION_NAME assigned.

Why do I still get a 0 in response?

Thanks

**UPDATE**
I've been manually putting debug output in admin-ajax.php just for the sake of curiosity.

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    /**
     * Fires authenticated AJAX actions for logged-in users.
     *
     * The dynamic portion of the hook name, `$_REQUEST['action']`,
     * refers to the name of the AJAX action callback being fired.
     *
     * @since 2.1.0
     */
    do_action( 'wp_ajax_' . $_REQUEST['action'] );
    var_dump('wp_ajax_' . $_REQUEST['action']);
} else {
    /**
     * Fires non-authenticated AJAX actions for logged-out users.
     *
     * The dynamic portion of the hook name, `$_REQUEST['action']`,
     * refers to the name of the AJAX action callback being fired.
     *
     * @since 2.8.0
     */
    do_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_' . $_REQUEST['action'] );
}
// Default status
die( '0' );
```

This is the core functionality with my var_dump added. My AJAX call GETS THERE and the output is CORRECT ACTION NAME defined in add_action in my plugin files, thought nothing is returned from my action/it's not being called and I get to the default `die( '0' );`

Bummer. Don't know what to do further.

Comment: Try this: `add_action( 'wp_ajax_setAsyncCheckProduct', array( $this, 'setAsyncCheckProduct' ) );`

Comment: Add `add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_setAsyncCheckProduct', [$this, 'setAsyncCheckProduct']);` too inside `assignAsyncEvents()`

Comment: @Nilambar your suggestion is just to remove shorthand array declaration.

Comment: @passatgt this is not working, nor it should, as I'm working in admin panel, the user is always logged in and privileged.

Comment: Just to experiment remove the var_dump() from the setAsyncCheckProduct() function. I want to say I ran into this issue a few months ago and want to say dumping inside that function caused me issues for some reason.

Comment: @DavidLabbe no effect. I'm already spending too much time on the simplest thing in the world.. :(

Comment: @DavidLabbe I did a manual debug in admin-ajax.php, it's weird, it goes into ``if (is_user_logged_in())`` and then ``do_action('wp_ajax_'.$_REQUEST['action']);`` which appears to be the correct action to call, but my code is not called :-/

Comment: Ok. I ran some test and got it to work fine for me in much the same way you have it. I did not get a response (response undefined) when the var_dump($_REQUEST); is in place. That does cause an the 'response undefined'. Double check your jQuery selectors and make sure that is selecting from the right source.

Comment: @BorisLapouga Look closer at the second comment by _passatgt_ which suggests that you use the `nopriv_` version which is **the solution** to your problem. You are just adding public calls to and expect to see guest calls go through closed routes designed for logged in users.

Comment: @kaiser Well, I did the nopriv action before writing a response. It's not working for me.

Comment: Further investigation in ``plugin.php`` my action gets stuck and never called in a: ``if ( !isset($wp_filter[$tag]) ) {
  if ( isset($wp_filter['all']) )
   array_pop($wp_current_filter);
  return;
 }`` code portion. Thoughts?

Comment: Please add the full trace (XDebug or similar) to your question. Also, please note that we already got a comment explosion that is hard to follow. Document your step with [edit]s to your question, please.

Comment: Where in your plugin is `add_action('admin_init', [$this, 'assignAsyncEvents']);` being called? And did remove the `var_dump($_REQUEST);` ....not that is causing the main issue but it will cause another when the main issue is fixed.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is where you place the add_action of your wp_ajax_*

Try to put it at the start of everything, and ensuring that it is being loaded in a /wp-admin/ route.

Try your url: http://xxx/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=your_action until it gives you something different than zero.

Comment: You save my day!

Answer (score 1):

Placing this answer for those people who're trying to fix the same issue.

It's important where

`add_action('wp_ajax_setAsyncCheckProduct', [$this, 'setAsyncCheckProduct']);`

resides.

In my case the issue was finally fixed moving a similar line to the main plugin file, where all concrete classes are included and initialised. Of course the line had to be changed to this form:

`add_action('wp_ajax_setAsyncCheckProduct', ['ClassName', 'setAsyncCheckProduct']);`